# What schema microdata to use on outgoing news links?

Tags: database-schema, schema.org

On a site I am working on, there will be a page that show all sorts of links that point to different news sources. (HoffPost , New York Post . . . )

The code will look something like this.

```
    <li>
     <h4>
       New York Times:
     </h4> 
     <small>2/3/2014</small>
     <a href="#link" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
        Title of New York Times Post
     </a>
    </li>
```

What is the best way to add schema data to this?
Would it be https://schema.org/NewsArticle ?

Comment: What is the purpose of the page? Is it just a list of newspapers? Ranked somehow? Or maybe a list of newspapers you worked for? Or newspapers that wrote about something specific?

Comment: It is just a list of newspapers that have said something about the site I am working on.

Kind of like a "Look who has talked about us" page.

Answer (score 1):

A newspaper could be represented by its [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization), a specific article by [`NewsArticle`](https://schema.org/NewsArticle).

As this is for newspaper articles that are about your site, you could use [`WebSite`](http://schema.org/WebSite) as domain and its [`citation`](http://schema.org/citation) or [`mentions`](http://schema.org/mentions) to reference the articles. However, it’s likely that the articles are not really about your *site* (well, unless it’s a Web app review or similar), but about your organization/product/service, in which case you’d want to use the appropriate type (however, appropriate properties to reference the articles might be missing then; `Product`, for example, would only offer a [property for reviews](http://schema.org/review), not for general articles about it).

Each `NewsArticle` could reference the newspaper with the [`publisher`](http://schema.org/publisher) and/or [`sourceOrganization`](http://schema.org/sourceOrganization) property.

With the [`about`](http://schema.org/about) property, you could reference your site/product (unless the article only [`mentions`](http://schema.org/mentions) you).

```html
<body prefix="schema: http://schema.org/">

  <article typeof="schema:NewsArticle">

    <div property="schema:publisher schema:sourceOrganization" typeof="schema:Organization">
      <p property="schema:name">The Guardian</p>
    </div>

    <div property="schema:about" typeof="schema:Product">
      <link property="schema:url" href="http://example.com/" />
    </div>

    <!-- article URL, title, teaser etc. -->

  </article>

  <article typeof="schema:NewsArticle">
    <!-- … -->
  </article>

</body>
```